# Customizing CFileDialog error messages

Tags: c++, mfc, cfiledialog

It would be nice if there is a way to customize the `CFileDialog` error messages.

For example, Entering an invalid drive in the **File name** edit box causes an error message like below.

[image: Invalid Drive]

I want to show a **different error** here. Is it possible *without subclassing* `CFileDialog`?

**It is also fine if the dialog returns instead of showing error.**

Here is the code snippet:

```
CFileDialog dlgFile( TRUE, 0, 0,  OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT, szFilters, 0, 0, 0 );
dlgFile.m_ofn.FlagsEx |= OFN_EX_NOPLACESBAR;
dlgFile.m_ofn.lpstrTitle= csTitle;
dlgFile.m_ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;

const int nMaxFiles = 2512;
const int nBuffSize = ( ( nMaxFiles * ( MAX_PATH + 1 ) ) + 1 ) * sizeof( TCHAR );
dlgFile.GetOFN().lpstrFile = new TCHAR[ nBuffSize ];
::ZeroMemory( dlgFile.GetOFN().lpstrFile, nBuffSize );
dlgFile.GetOFN().nMaxFile = nBuffSize;
if( dlgFile.DoModal() == IDOK )
{
   ...
   ...
}
```

Comment: MFC just adds a thin wrapper around the file dialog built into Windows; you're asking if there's a way to change a Windows built-in dialog.

Comment: No I wasn't. I was asking whether there is a way that the 'thin wrapper' you mentioned can make it behave differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it's ok just to modify the dialog, you can install a hook [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with WH_CBT.

Comment: Can you explain how to use the hook procedure to handle the case of mentioned error? I think here, the events to be hooked is two: The return on *File name edit box* and Click on *Open button*. Can I use a WH_CBT hook to achieve that?

Comment: Your callback will be called for a number of events (activating, creating, destroying, minimizing, maximizing, moving, or sizing a window, etc). This way you have the hwnd of the dialogbox/error message and sub-controls and can modify them .See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644977(v=vs.85).aspx for details

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that setting `OFN_NOVALIDATE` to `m_ofn.Flags` removes this validation and returns from the dialog without showing that warning.

Comment: It will be nice if there is a way of showing a different warning without returning from the dialog.